# Getting input from console without cin?

Tags: c++, c, console

I'm trying to make a little console program that will basically be console pong. So right now I have this:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        clearScreen();
        restThread(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only input I need to poll is if the user has pressed the A or D key since the screen was cleared. I will also need to know when the key is released. I'm also trying to do this cross platform.

so really all I need is like an if(keyWasDown('a')) {} sort of function.

Thanks

Comment: There's no standard way. Any answers you get are going to be platform-specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you want [kbhit](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html) (non-blocking) or [getch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) (blocking), both from `<conio.h>`. There's also [getchar](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/getchar.html), from `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`.

If you want the program to wait for a keyboard press, `getch` or `getchar` by themselves will do.

If you **don't** want the program to wait for a keyboard press, `kbhit` combined with either `getch` or `getchar` will suffice.

However, as GMan said, these methods are not really cross platform (if you never intend to try this on different platforms, that's moot, really). For console games, you might be interested looking into [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: At least Windows. I know it doesn't work on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        clearScreen();

        if(kbhit())
        {
            int const ch = getch();
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 0x61: printf("A was pressed!\n"); break;
            case 0x64: printf("D was pressed!\n"); break;
            }
        }

        restThread(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```